# Modified parsed bound attribute without isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
    <p>{{ values.data }}</p>
    <div foo-bar="values.data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`values.data` is defined in `FooController`, and it's passed to the `fooBar` attribute directive (which doesn't has an isolated scope) so that this directive can modify it directly.

In the `fooBar` directive, I'm parsing the attribute and assigning a value, however, the value in `FooController` is not getting modified, just the local `fooBar`'s copy.

How can I accomplish this?

I created a Codepen demonstrating this: http://codepen.io/jviotti/pen/ghnkc?editors=101
In the Codepen, the printed text should be `Baz`, not `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you the issue solution in js as i am not familiar with Coffee. The syntax to set data with parse is different

```
getter = $parse(attributes.fooBar);
setter=getter.assign;
setter(scope,"Baz");
```

Also see the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lzkoq) is one solution using the scope directly:

```
app.directive 'fooBar', ($parse) ->
  restrict: 'E'
  link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
    scope.values.data = 'Baz'
```

BTW: I just saw that you restrict you driective to element (`'E'`) and try to apply it as attribute in your example. This way the directive is not applied.

Comment: The `restrict: E` was an issue in the Codepen. It should have been `A`. As my question title says, I'm trying to accomplish this without an isolated scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that. Why do you not want to use a scope?

Comment: It's important for my directive to not create an isolated not children scope. It's some kind of decorator.

Comment: Ok, I updated my solution. You just can access the scope and modify it directly.